# Change position of hint using simple form and bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Rails 3.1x, SimpleForm 2.1, and Bootstrap 2.2.x, and I want to change the position of the hint text on some of my forms.

Currently if I use code such as the following (this is a simplified version)

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :name, :hint => 'this should be your first name' %>

  ..
  ..
```

I will get a form looks like this

[image]

However, I would like it to look like this.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: This question needs to have the rendered HTML markup added, along with any custom CSS (outside of Bootstrap). Then we will have more information to help you with.

Comment: You can put a placeholder , that would look more elegant . Just a suggestion

Comment: I have no extra CSS, this is vanilla bootstrap and simpleform

Comment: Placeholder is an interesting thought, although it seems to be a total departure from what I have already been doing, it seems an interesting direction

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure its works well but try this , in your form field add class

```
 <%= f.input :name, :hint => 'this should be your first name' , :class => "someclass"%>
```

and in application.css

```
.somecalss
      { 
           width:somevalue;
            }
```